# How do I fix this Apt error?

Tags: apt, updates

When I try updating my system this error pops up.

Can anyone help?

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pasgui/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
```

Comment: The PPA doesn't appear to provide any packages for Xenial - see https://launchpad.net/~pasgui/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: The link provided in this question doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This repository does not support Xenial.

If you need `codeblocks`, add the official PPA for the latest version (https://launchpad.net/~damien-moore/+archive/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable) or install it from the official repositories.

If you need `builddeb`, just install it from the official repositories (bzr-builddeb).

If you need DoUML, run:

```
git clone https://github.com/DoUML/douml.git
make
make install
```

Do be warned that DoUML is not completed and is still a work in progress.

If you need `premake`, the one in the official repositories should fit your needs (premake4).

If you need `scite`, just install the one from the official repositories.